# Messing with erlang and gen_event behaviour

Tags: erlang

In a concept proof I'm developing, I've built the folowing scheme:

```
   _ A _ _
  /  |  \ \
 SS  S   H CC
    / \
   C   C
```

In which:
A - Application

SS - Supervisor

CC - "Real" client

S - gen_server

H - gen_event

C - "internal" client

The application works like a multiplexer. I connect on my internal client on my server and request some stuff. Then I pass this request to my real client (witch connects to the real application) and distribute it over any internal client who is demand that kind of stuff.

Everything is working fine except for the event handling: I wanted to make my internal client send messages directly to the gen_event handlers, and he would intermediate the process of requesting to the real server/ reading from cache and replying to the client.

I figured that I need to make a link between the event handler and my client handling process, this is right? Maybe it's the case to make the event handler to be a global process and just pump messages from between clients?

Sorry for the long question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question but *assuming* you are after a sort of *message switch* to enable Clients to exchange messages in a distributed fashion, you could look at one my projects that does just that: [Mswitch](http://erlang-mswitch.googlecode.com/).

Of course if you register a "global process" (accessible locally and/or remotely), you can always shuttle messages to it and have this process distribute the said messages as you see fit.  Be sure not to forget about the common pitfalls of making processes in different Emulator instances talk to each other (cookie sync and registered VM name).

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look on your project.

Answer (score -1):

If you register the handler, it will have a globally known name , and then you can send messages to it directly.

Comment: Yeah, I know that! but if I pass a message using "!", it will be handled on the handle_event's function?

Comment: No, it will handled by handle_info.